# JUnit Mockito Test: zero interactions

Tags: java, data-structures, junit, foreach, mockito

I want to test this a List of Objects using Junit and Mockito.

If the loop is formed so:

```
       List<Message> owner = new ArrayList<>();

   for (int i = 0; i < messageStorage.getMessage(us.getName()).size(); i++) {
            owner.add(new Message(us.getName() + " - " + messageStorage.getMessage(us.getName()).get(i).getText(),
                    messageStorage.getMessage(us.getName()).get(i).getTime()));
        }
    listOfMessages.addAll(owner);
```

The test in mockito works fine!

```
@Test
public void onTheWallTest() {
    when(clock.now()).thenReturn(parse("2014-12-03T10:15:30.00Z"));

    User follows = new User("someFollower");
    Mockito.when(userStorage.getUser(Matchers.anyString())).thenReturn(follows);
    wall.onTheWall();
    Mockito.verify(messageStorage).getMessage("someFollower");
}
```

When I use forEach/lambda in this way:

```
 IntStream.range(0, owner.size())
                .forEach(i ->
                        owner.add(new Message(us.getName() + " - " + messageStorage.getMessage(us.getName()).get(i).getText(),
                                messageStorage.getMessage(us.getName()).get(i).getTime()))
                );
        listOfMessages.addAll(owner);
```

The test fails with the response:

```
    Wanted but not invoked:
messageStorage.getMessage("someFollower");
-> at app.command.WallTest.onTheWallTest(WallTest.java:47)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

Comment: You only posted partial pieces of code, so it's hard to reason about it. But if owner is also initialized using `List<Message> owner = new ArrayList<>();` in your stream-based code, then `IntStream.range(0, owner.size())` is an empty stream. Iterating on an empty stream won't do anything.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I need to add a message into the test, to cover it.

Comment: Considering the fact, that string '.getUser(' can be found only once in the code and namely in the mocking, I believe the section which is actually triggers that mocking is not in the exerts provided.

Comment: @AndreyLebedenko: then, I can substitute a simple ordinary loop to Java 8/9 (lambda) and to works in mockito?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed so:

```
messageStorage.getMessage(us.getName())
              .stream()
              .map(item -> owner.add(
                  new Message(us.getName() + " - " + item.getText(), item.getTime())
              ));
```